# Verilog simulator or development environment on Mac OS

Tags: simulation, mac, verilog, development-tools

Is there a way to develop some Verilog designs on mac?

Comment: I think your best bet is VMWare and Windows XP

Comment: VirtualBox will be cheaper (free) and just as good. You might try running some software under Wine (using [Wineskin](http://wineskin.doh123.com/); don't worry it is not only for games) but "your mileage may vary". :)

Answer (score 1):

I hear that
[Icarus Verilog](http://www.icarus.com/eda/verilog/)
supports
[Macintosh OS X](http://iverilog.wikia.com/wiki/Installation_Guide#Macintosh_OS_X).

Answer (score 1):

You might try [verilator](http://www.veripool.org) if icarus verilog doesnt work for you.  Or perhaps even if it does.

Answer (score 0):

Going with what @Sergio Campama and @jpc mentioned, consider virtualization. If you wish to avoid Windows, various vendors including Model Sim support Linux. RHEL 5 is the most commonly supported one.